# How to Determine the Type of a PostgreSQL Database Object (Table, View, Function, Procedure, or Package)

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm working on a PostgreSQL database and need to check the type of a given object, whether it's a table, view, function, procedure, or even a package. Currently, I'm using multiple queries and conditions to determine the object type, but I wonder if there is a more straightforward way to achieve this with a single query or a more efficient method.

Here is a part of my current code:

```
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT relname, CASE relkind 
    WHEN 'r' THEN 'Table'
    WHEN 'v' THEN 'View'
    WHEN 'f' THEN 'Foreign Table'
    WHEN 'm' THEN 'Materialized View'
    WHEN 'p' THEN 'Partitioned Table'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS object_type
    FROM pg_class c
    JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
    WHERE n.nspname = %s AND c.relname = %s;
""", (schema_name, object_name))

object_type = cursor.fetchone()
if object_type is None:
    object_type = 'Unknown'
else:
    object_type = object_type[1]

if object_type == 'Unknown':
    sql = f"SELECT routine_name " \
        f"FROM information_schema.routines " \
        f"WHERE specific_schema = %s AND routine_name = %s"
    cursor.execute(sql, (schema_name, object_name))
    routine_exists = cursor.fetchone()
    if routine_exists:
        object_type = 'PROCEDURE/FUNCTION'
```

My question is twofold:

Is there a more straightforward way to determine the object type of a PostgreSQL database object directly or with a more efficient single query, possibly by joining tables, instead of my current approach?

How can I identify whether a database object is a package in PostgreSQL?

I tried the following:

Current Approach: I used multiple queries and conditions to identify the object type:
I checked the pg_class and pg_namespace tables to determine if it's a table or view.
If the object type was "Unknown," I queried the information_schema.routines table to find out if it's a function or procedure.

I'm seeking advice on streamlining the process of identifying the object type and any insights on recognizing packages, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way except to query all possible catalog tables for an object of that name. This can be more efficient than your code by using a single database query:

```
SELECT relname AS object_name,
       CASE relkind
          WHEN 'r' THEN 'table'
          WHEN 'i' THEN 'index'
          WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence'
          WHEN 't' THEN 'toast table'
          WHEN 'v' THEN 'view'
          WHEN 'm' THEN 'materialized view'
          WHEN 'f' THEN 'foreign table'
          WHEN 'p* THEN 'partitioned table'
          WHEN 'I' THEN 'partitioned index'
       END AS object_type
FROM pg_class
WHERE relname = %s
  AND relkind <> 'c'  -- will also be in pg_type
UNION ALL
SELECT proname,
       CASE prokind
          WHEN 'f' THEN 'function'
          WHEN 'p' THEN 'procedure'
          WHEN 'a' THEN 'aggregate function'
          WHEN 'w' THEN 'window function'
FROM pg_proc
WHERE proname = %s
UNION ALL
SELECT typname,
       CASE typtype
          WHEN 'b' THEN 'base type'
          WHEN 'c' THEN 'composite type'
          WHEN 'd' THEN 'domain'
          WHEN 'e' THEN 'enumeration type'
          WHEN 'p' THEN 'pseudo-type'
          WHEN 'r' THEN 'range type'
          WHEN 'm' THEN 'multirange type'
       END
FROM pg_type
WHERE typname = %s
UNION ALL
SELECT lanname, 'procedural language'
FROM pg_language
WHERE lanname = %s
UNION ALL
/* and do on for many other catalogs */
```

You'll have to add a branch for each possible object type.

Note that you should perhaps add the schema into your query, because most objects live in a schema, and two objects of the same type can have the same name if they are in different schemas.

Also note that the name is only unique per schema and object type. For example, there could be a table and a function with the same name in the same schema. Moreover, there is function overloading, so you can have different functions with the same name in the same schema.

Finally, note that for each table, view etc. there always exists a composite type with the same name.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution and valuable advice! Your query has greatly simplified the process of determining object types in PostgreSQL to me. I've updated it to include the schema filter as you suggested, and it's working perfectly for my use case. Your assistance is highly appreciated, and I'm grateful for your help! @Laurenz Albe